# How to completely fill several rows of images by varying their height and maintaining their aspect-ratio

Tags: html, css, flexbox, gallery, image-gallery

I have a design problem I’d like to solve via CSS, but I have the feeling It can be done just with a javascript.

I have a gallery of images of different sizes and proportions. I’d like them to:

1. distribute in more rows
2. adjust their sizes and row distribution according to a given maximum height and to the monitor size on which they are viewed
3. fill in all the space of a single row, with fixed margins between them

Here’s a sketch of what I’d like to accomplish

[image]

As you can see, the second row is higher than the first, in order to fill in all the space with the larger images, and I’m ok with that (it’s the only way this can be done).

I didn’t manage to achieve this. The best I could do is to equally distribute the images with fixed margins BUT with aspect-ratio totally messed up (I know the problem here is `min-width and max-height`… why can’t I give a `max-height` and adjust `width` consequentially?)

HTML

```
<div class="img-blocco">
    <img src=“1.jpg” /> <img src=“2.jpg” /> … <img src=“n.jpg” /> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
.img-blocco {
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 0 5%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.img-blocco img {
    margin: 0 5px 10px;
    min-width:200px;
    max-height:300px;
    flex-grow:1;
}
```

I obviously managed to equally distribute my images with their correct aspect-ratio spacing them with `justify-content: space-between`, but I don’t like this solution at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share a properly working codepen link?

Comment: Sure, here's a codepen with some random images with various size-ratios: https://codepen.io/Ada_Snufkin/pen/PQbzmy
As you can see, since the height is fixed, they just stretch horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking  - [Pen](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/OQbGxJ).

Note that the CSS property `object-fit` has issues with [browser support in ie11](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit). Let me know whether this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it's a bit too specific... I was looking for a sort of automatic solution, since the images are randomly taken from a database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.  I have a div holding all the images with the following CSS

```
#ImageHolder {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: left;
}
.thumbnail {
    height: 25vh;
    margin: 0.5vh 0.25vw 0.25vw 0.5vh;
    user-select: none;
}
```

I then use the following JS functions to wait until the items are all loaded `loadCheck()`, go through and find images with the same top position `adjustAll()`, then resize it to fill the entire row with `resize()`

For some reason, I have to run resize twice to get it to fit correctly, but it does work.

```
function resize(workinglist){
    var vw=window.innerWidth/100;
    var maxWidth=ImageHolder.getBoundingClientRect().width-(workinglist.length * 0.5 * vw);
    var totalWidth=0;
    for (x in workinglist){
        totalWidth+=workinglist[x].getBoundingClientRect().width
    }
    var ratio=2-(totalWidth/maxWidth);
    for (x in workinglist){
        workinglist[x].style.height=(workinglist[x].getBoundingClientRect().height*ratio)+"px";
    }
    var totalWidth=0;
    for (x in workinglist){
        totalWidth+=workinglist[x].getBoundingClientRect().width
    }
    return [totalWidth,maxWidth,ImageHolder.getBoundingClientRect().width,ratio];
}



function adjustAll(){
    var workinglist=[];
    var imgs=Array.from(ImageHolder.children);
    for (place in imgs) imgs[place].style.height="";
    var imgTop=imgs[0].getBoundingClientRect().top;
    for (place in imgs){
        if (imgs[place].getBoundingClientRect().top==imgTop){
            workinglist.push(imgs[place]);
        }else{
            resize(workinglist);
            resize(workinglist);
            workinglist=[];
            imgTop=imgs[place].getBoundingClientRect().top;
            workinglist.push(imgs[place]);
        }
    }
}

function loadCheck(){
     var imgs=Array.from(ImageHolder.children);
     for (place in imgs){
         if (! imgs[place].complete){
             console.log("Not Loaded yet");
             return false;
         }
     }
     adjustAll();
     clearInterval(lc);
     console.log("I resized everyone");
}

ls=setInterval(loadcheck,100);
```

I also add a function to check for window resize and run `adjustAll()` when that happens.

**NOTE**
you will need to adjust the effects of the margins in your code.  If you do padding, then you can remove the adjustments for margins in the resize function .

```
var maxWidth=ImageHolder.getBoundingClientRect().width-(workinglist.length * 0.5 * vw);
```

**BEFORE**

[image: Images before resize]

**AFTER**
[image: Images after resize]